# How to show that Fubini's theorem holds for PDF's

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions

I am working on an assignment with probability density functions. I am allowed to make assumptions such as Fubini's theorem, but I want to explain why it holds in this specific case rather that just blindly assume it.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini.27s_theorem_for_integrable_functions) I am trying to make sense of the theorem. That is: Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are $\sigma-$finite measure spaces, and suppose that $X \times Y$ is given the product measure (which is unique as $X$ and $Y$ are $\sigma-$finite). Fubini's theorem states that if $f(x,y)$ is $X \times Y$ integrable, meaning that it is measurable and $\int_{X\times Y}|f(x,y)|d(x,y)<\infty$ then $\int_X\left( \int_Y f(x,y) dy \right)dx = \int_Y\left( \int_X f(x,y) dx \right)dy = \int_{X\times Y}f(x,y)d(x,y)$

It is clear that $\int_{X\times Y}|f(x,y)|d(x,y)<\infty$ as probability density functions are non negative and the area beneath is $1$.

How can I show that for random variables $X$ and $Y$ Fubini's theorem holds? I have not yet encountered measures so this is not making sense to me.